# Socket bind failed on sockaddr_in without bzero

Tags: c, sockets, bind

I write a little socket programm that only bind to specified ip:port, but bind() failed if the struct sockaddr_in is not bzero and gcc is with option -O2.

Here is the codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    //bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons((unsigned short)9009);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &addr.sin_addr);

    int sock;
    if((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1){
        perror("socket error");
        exit(0);
    }   
    if(bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1){
        printf("socket error: %d, %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(0);
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Please notice `bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));` is commented out, I intend to initial the sockadd_in by each member. Compile and run:

```
$ gcc a.c; ./a.out
OK

$ gcc -O2 a.c; ./a.out 
socket error: 49, Can't assign requested address
```

We can know the struct sockadd_in is defined as:

```
struct in_addr {
  in_addr_t   s_addr;           /* 32-bit IPv4 address */
                                /* network byte ordered */
};

struct sockaddr_in {
  uint8_t         sin_len;      /* length of structure (16) */
  sa_family_t     sin_family;   /* AF_INET */
  in_port_t       sin_port;     /* 16-bit TCP or UDP port number */
                                /* network byte ordered */
  struct in_addr  sin_addr;     /* 32-bit IPv4 address */
                                /* network byte ordered */
  char            sin_zero[8];  /* unused */
};
```

My question is, does the bind() implementation depends on sockaddr_in.sin_zero being cleared?

**Edit: Mac OS X, Darwin Kernel Version 12.4.0 X86_64**

Comment: I would recommend printing the value of errno when the bind fails. That should tell us a little more about the failure.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue (started program in loop several thousands times). However, clearing structure is good practice, especially when you already encountered error once.

Comment: You aren't setting the 'sin_len' field. I would fix that and retest.

Comment: @keltar Did you compile with -O2 option? After finding this issue, I always reset the sockaddr_in after define it.

Comment: @ideawu Yes i did. Even tried -O3, with no difference. Debian testing & gcc 4.7, if that matters.

Comment: @keltar well, it only happens on my Mac OS X, Darwin Kernel Version 12.4.0 X86_64... it does not happen on Ubuntu Linux I just tested.

Comment: @ideawu just curious - have you tried setting sin_len to zero as EJP suggested? Please tell the results. It seems unlikely someone would be keeping anything in sin_zero, but it still possible.

Comment: maybe inet_pton is at fault? (converting string to binary form maybe without null termination? so it will gather garbage from addr). Maybe try doing inet_ntop and check if address is properly converted back?

Comment: @keltar sin_len = 0 tested, failed.

Comment: @zoska inet_ntop() return s 1, but bind() still fails

Comment: @ideawu I'm not asking about what `inet_ntop` returns. I'm asking to reconvert binary form of address created by `inet_ntop` back to string using `inet_pton` and see what happens. Also you used almost the same format for `socket` and `bind` error log. Don't do this in future.

Comment: POSIX requires a `struct sockaddr_in` to contain only `sin_family`, `sin_addr` and `sin_port`. It *allows* other members, but portable programs cannot access those. Requiring programs to *indirectly* set up these nonportable fields with a `memset 0` is **simply broken**.

Answer (score 1):

The  rules used in name binding vary between address families. and there's also this sin_zero field in struct sockaddr_in which some people claim must be set to zero. Other people don't claim anything about it (the Linux documentation doesn't even mention it at all), and there are other documentation which claim sin_zero has been removed from struct sockaddr_in,
 I have tried with both bzero commented and un-commented. The commented works good some time in a local network but un-commented version works all time either local network or not. so i guess bzeroing is good practice.

Comment: POSIX doesn't document any `sin_zero`; it only allows a `sockaddr_in` to have additional members beside the standard three.